# JSONDecodeError when processing dataframe column that is supposed to be a json

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a column in a dataframe that is supposed to contain information that corresponded to a json.

I tried the following methods to load the data:

```
pd.io.json.json_normalize(sr_df.signal_inputs.apply(json.loads))
```

```
sr_df.signal_inputs.apply(json.loads).values.tolist()
```

but when I try to load the information contained in the column to do some data transformation I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-bdc3a3932f07> in <module>
----> 1 test = pd.io.json.json_normalize(sr_df.signal_inputs.apply(json.loads))
      2 test.head()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3846             else:
   3847                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3848                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3849 
   3850         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    349     if cls is None:
    350         cls = JSONDecoder

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

can anyone help me understand what is causing this error and how I can possibly fix it?

EXTRA INFO: some rows in this column were None and I converted them to nan, I don't know if this might contribute to the issue.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you sure you need to apply `json.loads`?

Comment: At this point I am unsure of everything, what do you think I should use?

Comment: if it's a `requests` response, could you share URL to reproduce the data?

Comment: No, I don't have access to the URL, I only have access to what is in a database, that I can then load to a dataframe and appears in a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to update this because I found the answer, there was a rogue none in the json column, once it was removed the json started loading perfectly.